# Upload 100Gb to azure blob storage

Tags: azure-blob-storage

I am trying to upload a 100GB dadate. For this I have taken the following example from the Internet:

Unfortunately, the file does not appear in Azure, even though the upload does not produce any errors. Smaller files, on the other hand, appear after the upload.

Is it even possible to upload a 100GB file to Azure Blob?I have tried many example listngs, but not has worked?
Do I need to go to AWS?

Here my code:

```
public void UploadStreamAsync(string file)
    {
         var fileInfo = new FileInfo(file);

        CloudBlockBlob myBlob = _container.GetBlockBlobReference(fileInfo.Name);
        var blockSize = 1024 * 1024;
        myBlob.StreamWriteSizeInBytes = blockSize;
        var fileName = fileInfo.FullName;
        long bytesToUpload = fileInfo.Length;
        long fileSize = bytesToUpload;

        if (bytesToUpload < blockSize)
        {
            CancellationToken ca = new CancellationToken();
            var ado = myBlob.UploadFromFileAsync(fileName);
            Console.WriteLine(ado.Status); //Does Not Help Much
            ado.ContinueWith(t =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Status = " + t.Status);
                Console.WriteLine("It is over"); //this is working OK
            });
        }
        else
        {
            List<string> blockIds = new List<string>();
            int index = 1;
            long startPosition = 0;
            long bytesUploaded = 0;
            do
            {
                var bytesToRead = Math.Min(blockSize, bytesToUpload);
                var blobContents = new byte[bytesToRead];
                using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open))
                {
                    fs.Position = startPosition;
                    fs.Read(blobContents, 0, (int)bytesToRead);
                }
                ManualResetEvent mre = new ManualResetEvent(false);
                var blockId = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(index.ToString("d6")));
                Console.WriteLine("Now uploading block # " + index.ToString("d6"));
                blockIds.Add(blockId);
                var ado = myBlob.PutBlockAsync(blockId, new MemoryStream(blobContents), null);
                ado.ContinueWith(t =>
                {
                    bytesUploaded += bytesToRead;
                    bytesToUpload -= bytesToRead;
                    startPosition += bytesToRead;
                    index++;
                    double percentComplete = (double)bytesUploaded / (double)fileSize;
                    Console.WriteLine("Percent complete = " + percentComplete.ToString("P"));
                    mre.Set();
                });
                mre.WaitOne();
            }
            while (bytesToUpload > 0);
            Console.WriteLine("Now committing block list");
            var pbl = myBlob.PutBlockListAsync(blockIds);
            pbl.ContinueWith(t =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Blob uploaded completely.");
            });
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Comment: I noticed that you're doing a lot of Console.Writeline in your code. What's the last message you see in the console? You can certainly upload 100GB file in Azure.

Comment: i don't get an error. but i don't see the file in the azure portal. maybe you have a working example? 
the ones from the internet only work when you upload a few MB...

Comment: Can you share the console output (just the last few 10 - 15 outputs)?

Comment: i have to run it again. had all outputs in the console. i log now and send it then ;)

Comment: See if you can also log the output in a file as well so that you don't have to run again to capture the error. Also, I would recommend running your code from an Azure VM that is in the same region as your storage account. Upload will be much-much faster.

Comment: More than likely the issue is with your block size. Currently it is set as 1 MB (1024 x 1024). Since you're splitting your 100 GB file in 1 MB blocks, the total number of blocks you're uploading is 102400 which is more than the max allowed blocks (50000). Please try by changing the block size to 4 MB.

Comment: may i send you an email with the log?

Comment: No need to email. Just upload it somewhere on the cloud (like pastebin) and share the link. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, here is the log: 
https://pastebin.com/Pqyghr1r
Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2):

The reason your upload is failing is because the number of blocks (102400) in which you are splitting your blob is more than maximum number of blocks allowed (50000) in a block blob.

To fix the problem, please increase your block size from 1MB to 4MB (or more depending on your internet speed). That way your number of blocks will be around 25000.

What you need to do is essentially change the following line of code:

```
var blockSize = 1024 * 1024;
```

to

```
var blockSize = 4 * 1024 * 1024;
```

The basic idea is to keep the number of blocks in a block blob to be less than 50000.

To learn more, please see this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-block#remarks.

Comment: Hi, yes. Now it is on azure. Many thanks!
Why is the size of the uploaded file different?
On my local drive 100 GB (107,374,182,400 bytes) and on the azure 3.13 GiB?

Comment: Should I calculate the size: 3GiB * Blocksize = 3Gib * 32 *1024 * 1024?

Comment: If I get the lengt of the blob:
myBlob.Properties.Length; 
I get only 3355443200. How I can get the correct size?

Comment: If I downlaod the file form azure portal (download button) I get a file with the size of 3,355,443,200 bytes....

Comment: There's something else. Can you edit your question and add your latest code as an update to the question?  Please do not change the original code you posted as it will change the context of the question. Alternately, you can copy the code on pastebin and share the link of that.